# Xcode 5.1.1 Provisioning Profile Refresh

Tags: macos, refresh, provisioning-profile

When trying to refresh a provisioning profile in xcode 5.1.1 I am getting an error

"the data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format"

is anyone else aware of this issue?

Thanks

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683803/localizable-strings-files-in-xcode4

Comment: Having the same problem. Looks like this is likely Apple's fault

Comment: GAHHH - supposed to release today - same issue here.

Comment: It just started working again.

Comment: Yeah came back into work this morning and its now working again. Glad to know it wasn't just me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is old but I thought I would answer it for completeness. It turned out that there was a problem on Apple's end with the provisioning profiles and after leaving it for a bit it worked again as usual.