# XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError in Xcode

Tags: xcode, plist

When I try to run my project, I get this error, pointing to my localized .strings file:

[image: Screenshot of the error.]

> read failed: The operation couldn’t be completed. (`XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError` error 1.)

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 17):

There is a formatting error inside the .string file that the error is pointing at. Localizable .strings files should contain **strings in quotes** (if they contain more than one word and/or special characters) and **semicolons** at the end of lines, like such:

```
string = translation;
"another string" = "another translation";
```

Please refer to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24358129/3151675) to find the error.

You should execute

```
/usr/bin/plutil -lint <path to .strings file>
```

in Terminal to find the exact issue.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I had a conflict in info.plist which I forgot to resolve.

Answer (score 5):

This quite common when you have info.plist file with wrong structure.

Answer (score 2):

For flutter dev

Change from

```
<key>UISupportsDocumentBrowser</key>
<bool>true</bool>
```

to

```
<key>UISupportsDocumentBrowser</key>
<true/>
```

Answer (score 2):

For me I got error `XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 2.)`. It happened for combination `INFOPLIST_OTHER_PREPROCESSOR_FLAGS = -traditional` and `INFOPLIST_PREFIX_HEADER` which contained comments started with `//`. So I fixed it by changing comments to old style: `/* */`

Answer (score 1):

if you use Firebase, delete GoogleService-Info.plist file and download again