# Flutter iOS simulator can't run

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator, vmware

I tried to run the iOS simulator for Flutter in VMware. I get this in the console:

```
error: unable to read property list from file:

/Users/xxxxxx/ios/Runner/Info.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed.
(XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 1.) (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but
the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target
'shared_preferences' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but
the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.1.99. (in target 'Runner' from
project 'Runner')
```

How can I solve it?

This is my *info.plist* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
        <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
        <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
        <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
        <string>6.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleName</key>
        <string>JiyanUQuran</string>
        <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
        <string>APPL</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
        <string>????</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
        <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
        <string>LaunchScreen</string>
        <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
        <string>Main</string>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
        <false/>
        <key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>

    <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46792197/xcbutil-propertylistconversionerror-in-xcode)

Comment: sorry no , I add info.plist file detail can you check it?

Comment: This is not valid XML (non-matching `</dict>`).

Comment: yes I found my the mistake both of las <true/>  </dict> superfluous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not running VMware on Apple hardware (and why would you?), please stop.  Apple's license does not permit Apple's development applications (like Xcode) to run on non-Apple hardware.  Please stop breaking the law.

Comment: thanks alot ,really I didnt know this law ,I wont do that

Comment: Unsure, but they either have a deal with Apple to rent hardware, or they are paying a commercial licensing fee that isn't what we have with our EULA.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the mistake by removing last two line :

```
<true/>
    </dict>
```